# Does it make sense to add ATMHud to tabBarController.view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

When i try to add ATMHud to uitableviewcontroller subview it does work but it doesn't disable the scrolling and if the tableview is not on top i can't see the hud view.  What i did was added to teh tabBarController.view that works but i want find out if this is a good idea or later on i might have issues with it.

Another question is tabBarController.view frame is that the whole screen or just the bottom part.  How come atmhud shows in the middle of the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Yan

============
Found a blog post that shows how to reset self.view and add tableview separately in uitableviewcontroller

[UITableViewController and fixed sub views](http://herrray.com/uitableviewcontroller-and-fixed-sub-views/)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!tableView &&
        [self.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            tableView = (UITableView *)self.view;
    }

    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
        [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    UIView *fixedBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
    fixedBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:
        0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
    [self.view addSubview:fixedBar];
    [fixedBar release];                       
}
```

After this when add hud to self.view you will be able to disable the tableview on the bottom.
Let me know if this a good way to setup the tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using the tab bar is that the hud is now modal, and the user cannot change the tab.

It sounds like the tableview is not your primary viewm, as it can get "covered up". If its not the primary view, then add the ATMHud to self.view. If the tableView is the same as self.view, then add a new transparent view to it, then add the HUD to that view.

The tabBarController.view is the view that hosts the tabbed views - if you want to see its size (or frame) log it using NSStringFromCGRect(self.tabBarController.frame);

EDIT: I just did a test, the ATMHud DOES block the UI. All I can think of is that you have not inserted it where you need to (at the top of current view's subviews.) I have a demo project where I do this:

```
hud = [[ATMHud alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:hud.view];
[hud setCaption:@"Howdie"];
[hud setActivity:YES];
[hud show];
[hud hideAfter:5];
```

A button under the hud is not active - in fact nothing in the view is active (probably the Nav Bar would be live though)

If you want an ARCified and field tested version, you can grab it [here](https://github.com/dhoerl/ATMHud)

EDIT2: The solution to your problem is below. Note that ATMHud blocks clicks from getting to the table, and the code below stops the scrolling:

```
- (void)hudWillAppear:(ATMHud *)_hud
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
- (void)hudDidDisappear:(ATMHud *)_hud
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Dump the views:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "UIView+Utilities.h"

@interface UIView (Utilities_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)v toStr:(NSMutableString *)str;

@end

@implementation UIView (Utilities_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)a toStr:(NSMutableString *)str
{
    [str appendFormat:@"  %@: frame=%@ bounds=%@ layerFrame=%@ tag=%d userInteraction=%d alpha=%f hidden=%d\n", 
        NSStringFromClass([a class]),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.frame),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.bounds),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.layer.frame),
        a.tag, 
        a.userInteractionEnabled,
        a.alpha,
        a.isHidden
        ];
}

@end

@implementation UIView (Utilities)

+ (void)dumpSuperviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    while(v) {
        [self appendView:v toStr:str];
        v = v.superview;
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

+ (void)dumpSubviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    if(v) [self appendView:v toStr:str];
    for(UIView *a in v.subviews) {
        [self appendView:a toStr:str];
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Didn't realize that this made the tab bar frozen.  I guess there is no easy way to put a view on top of tableview if its a uitableviewcontroller.  When i add to self.view it adds to the tableview but doesn't freeze it and you can scroll it offscreen.  I wonder is it a question or the title got me down voted?

Comment: I'm using this class (I have a fork of it on github) and its been just great. I had to add my own view to put over the view before the HUD was added to intercept user action, but when I looked at ATMHud it was doing the same. I need to investigate further... I'll get back here soon.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  I think this only happens when I have a table view controller.  When i have a regular viewcontroller with a taleview and i have [self.view addsubivew:hud.view] then the ATMHud does intercept user action. I read some posts here that it's harder to put a view on top of a tableview when its in tableview controller.  Not sure if that is correct.

Comment: That make sense.  I think the only problem is that if the table is not scrolled to top the hudview doesn't show up.  I will double check on that.  I should scroll it to top anyway before refreshing it so this will work.  Thanks again for taking the time!  I am going to download the version of ATMHud from your link.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I installed your version of ATMHud and it works great but I am having a weird issue on one of the views. I am using parse.com and their uitableviewcontroller to show data. Before this was working fine but now the first time data loads the hud shows up in the top right corner of the screen under the navigation bar and I cannot hide it right away. It only hides when i refresh the table and show it again then hud resets and comes up in the middle of the screen. I can't seems to figure out why. Is there i can debug this to see why it comes up on top. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed it actually moved from center to the up left corner i guess location (0,0).  This is what i get from this log NSLog(@"center x -> %f y - > %f",self.loadingHud.view.center.x, self.loadingHud.view.center.y);  center x -> 160.000000 y - > 240.000000
Any ideas why would it move.  Thanks again!

Comment: How/when did it move? I created a simple project with a table, added the hud and it was all working just great. Now this is my ATMHud fork. I had posted them removed code to walk the view hierarchy (and look at frames, not centers). I'll post it again and you can dump the view hierarchy (log it) and see what is what. ATMHud tries to center the view in the hosting view.

Comment: I think this might be an edge case.  It only happens when i use parse.com's PFQueryTableViewController and when i am using caching with the table.  Otherwise in all the other parts of the app the hud display works properly

Comment: I think i got it.  I am calling hide probably numerous times way before show. I doing "lazy extension" and i am not adding the hudview until a bit latter.  I think it was not a problem with the original ATMHud but here might be some issue.  If you won't let me know what i can do to help to figure out why is this happening in your fork.

Comment: When I create the hud, I show it. If you are doing really non-standard things who knows the problem. Re-write your code so you know WHEN you want a hud, then create it, configure it, show it. Also, if using ARC, you MUST keep a strong reference to the HUD which you mil when it sends the last delegate message that its closed.

Comment: I hope it's not an issue using these comments as back and forth.  Was there any changes with hide animation?  When i do hideafter:0.1 then it works.  Is it possible the hide is really fast right after the show?